# Are general networking/protocol questions on topic here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-topics

I know questions about specific web services are off topic here.

But there are general networking questions about protocols that don’t involve a web service nor they are related to a professional task *(off‑topic on Server Fault)*.

Some examples include :

- As per ɪᴀɴᴀ specifications, an authorization code is necessary for requesting a domain name transfer to a registrar. In which ʀꜰᴄ it’s defined ?
- Is there a network protocol that use amplitude modulated radio signals ?
- What is the difference of purpose between Registry Registrar Protocol (rrp) and Extensible Provisioning Protocol (epp) ?

Would it be ok to ask such questions here ?

Comment: [This was asked 5 years ago.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88303/where-can-i-ask-questions-for-networking)  [Network Engineering. Stack Exchange](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) would be the correct place.

Comment: @Ramhound : [it isn’t](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26653/22743). I fear this should be directed [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95424).

Comment: All I can say is that, very few people at Superuser, would be able to answer those questions, and in my opinion are outside of the scope of Superuser.  It also Seems like calling these questions "general networking questions" isn't a good description for your questions, if they are not on topic at the networking engineering SE website.

Comment: @Ramhound : they are general in the mean they aren’t related to something like professional. Networking questions are ok networking engineering.se only if they are relevant to a professional matter. [Mine](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/26653/22743) wasn’t and as you can see, this the reason why it was closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your examples I would have to say that all three of those questions are off topic here.

From the [help centre](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a
>   question about …
>
> - computer hardware,
> - computer software, or
> - **personal and home computer networking**

Your first and third questions fail to meet the requirements for **personal** computer networking

Your second example is essentially a shopping recommendation for "go find me some network protocols" and would also be off topic as too broad.